# Prevent user from entering smaller value than previous input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am student testing and learning new things. Right now I'm trying to make a GUI fan speed controller. While I have made the basic code, I want that the user cant enter smaller value than previous input.

Javscript code

```
// 30
var range3 = document.getElementById("range3");
var num3 = document.getElementById('num3');

range3.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
num3.value = e.target.value;
});
num3.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
range3.value = e.target.value;
});


// 40
var range4 = document.getElementById("range4");
var num4 = document.getElementById('num4');

range4.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
num4.value = e.target.value;
});
num4.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
range4.value = e.target.value;
});

// 50
var range5 = document.getElementById("range5");
var num5 = document.getElementById('num5');

range5.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
num5.value = e.target.value;
});
num5.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
range5.value = e.target.value;
});


function execute(){                            
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  num3.value + " " +  num4.value + " " + num5.value ;
}
```

HTML code

```
     <input id="range3"  type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <input id="num3" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />

        <input id="range4"  type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <input id="num4" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />

        <input id="range5"  type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <input id="num5" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />

        <button onclick="execute()">Click</button>
        <p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: If not prevent , show error after.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: To get error if num3 > num4 or if num4>5 and so on.

Comment: OK, but you didn't write the `execute` function at all? That's why we can't see where you get stuck. Your question already contains code to read the values of the forms, so you can start there! (`document.getElementById('num3').value`)

Comment: Not really stuck anywhere, jut wanted add some extra features. Mainly I wanted to not let the user add greater. But I will try letting user enter anything but giving error in place of execute function. Something like if num3>num4 (error); else execute.